# How to check if Regional Languages are installed on windows OS

Tags: c#, windows, unicode

My software depends on the [Indic script : 'Regional and Language Options' in control panel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Enabling_complex_text_support_for_Indic_scripts#Windows_XP_and_Server_2003) (Unicode support) to be installed on windows pc

Using C# How do I check if the unicode is installed on the pc?

[image: Regional and Language Options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IsValidLocale` with the locale ID that you want.

And you can build the locale using `MAKELCID` and the language codes in WinNT.h (for instance 0x439 is Hindi, `MAKELCID(LANG_HINDI,SUBLANG_DEFAULT)`)

Comment: 'IsValidLocale' function is in which class?